# How to make a search for item and show the result in seperated page [ASP MVC]

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, search, razor

I just want to make a search for my site , and before I start work on that I just want to sort my work steps .

My site type is books site . and here is what I want to know :

1. I have a search box in my navbar .
2. when someone entered a book name to search I want to show the result of this
   search in this page :

   ```
   Localhost/Search?string=C++
   ```
3. How I can call the method that will process the search from the view
   ?
4. How should the controller method looks like , also the view page.
5. How to make a paging to the search page ?

I don't need a code , I just want from someone to help me with a list of steps I should do , to make the search as I requested and thanks a lot guys ....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can keep your input box for search inside a form and keep the form's method value to be GET.

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Search", "Students", FormMethod.Get, null))
{
   <input type="text" name="searchTerm" />
   <input type="submit" />
}
```

Now you should have an action method called `Search` inside your `StudentsController` which accepts a string value in a parameter named `searchTerm`.

```
public ActionResult Search(string searchTerm)
{
  // use searchTerm variable to get data and pass to view
  return View();
}
```

Now in your view (`~/Views/Students/Search.cshtml`), you can use the passed data to display the search results.

For paging, you may add another parameter to your action method which you will use to get a specific sub set of the data.

```
public ActionResult Search(string searchTerm,int page=1,size=10)
{
   // use searchTerm variable to get data and pass to view
   // page number is in page variable 
   // size is in size variable
   return View();
}
```

Now you need to adjust your view to show all the page numbers and link to the same action method and pass the page number in url like

```
/Students/Search?searchTerm=Java&page=2&size=25
```

Comment: it's worked but the paging not works , maybe I missed something , can you explain to me more about paging and thanks

Comment: You basically need to write code to divide the total number of items by the size and send that to the view along with your data (to be displayed) and display it.